# Can't verify a registered ENS callback

Tags: marketing-cloud

We're using Event Notification Service to declare a webhook, which will handle every link click in ou email. We are using the REST API (Node.js) to do so and it works.

After a successful registration we receive the following body :

```
callbackName: '---',
callbackId: '---',
url: '---',
signatureKey: '---',
maxBatchSize: 1000
```

We then use the `callbackId` and `signatureKey` as parameters for verifying the webhook, mandatory step before subscribing to events.

But our verification code always receives the following :

```
message: 'MCMS_UWH_Runtime_ObjectNotFound_callbackNotVerified: Callback not verified', errorcode: 30003
```

And when listing our registration it is actually not verified and thus non-usable for subscription.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are surely using the `Signature Key` returned after registering you callback, when you should actually use the `Registration Key` your end point receives during the registration. Those are different.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use MC front end, in setup :

[image]

From there, you can:

- Register a callback
- Verify it
- Declare the events you callback will receive

No code required